# Strange function behavior in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I'm doing the following sort of code in a project of mine, and the result of it is confusing me.

```
function changeSomethingsValue (thingToChange) {
    thingToChange = "something else";
}

var something = "something";

changeSomethingsValue(something);

console.log(something); // prints out "something"
```

I'm confused as to why the value of the `something` variable is still the string "something" after it had been passed through the `changeSomethingsValue` function. Why is this happening and how do I get the function to assign the new value to whatever variable gets passed in?

Comment: You don't, that's not how JavaScript works. You can change an object's *properties* from its reference, though.

Comment: Why the down-vote, though? I'd think this is a valid question.

Comment: arguments are private variables, so you're only changing a copy of the argument, not the upstream original string. it wouldn't matter if you passed an object, if you replace the local, nothing happens outside the function. you can re-assign _something_ in the function (instead of _thingToChange_ ), and that _would_ affect the original (but not the local).

Comment: @jfrej Probably because it's a mega-dupe, and tends to be searchable, but I'm guessing.

Comment: JavaScript is pass-by-value. *Assigning* a value to a variable or property **does not** change the value of another variable or property (exceptions: global scope, `with`, fancy things like getters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When passing primitives, like a string or a number, it's passed by value.  What you're expecting is for it to be passed by reference.

The fix would be to set `something` to the return value of `changeSomethingsValue`

```
function changeSomethingsValue (thingToChange) {
    thingToChange = "something else";

    return thingToChange;
}

var something = "something";

something = changeSomethingsValue(something);

console.log(something); // prints out "something"
```

Comment: If you're going this route then you should use the `return` keyword in the function.

Comment: And if you're going this route, it doesn't make sense to use `thingToChange` parameter and pass `something` into the function.

Comment: If you passed an object and reassigned the parameter reference in the function it wouldn't do what the OP is asking either.

Comment: @jfrej, right obviously -- this whole function doesn't make sense, but it was in response to the question.  @DaveNewton, you're right, it's not changing the reference, but it's ultimately changing the value of `something` which I do believe is what he was looking for -- not a deep understanding of passing references around in javascript.

Comment: FYI, objects are also pass by value. Passing an object instead would exhibit the same behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Parameters are passed by value, not by reference. In the case of a string, the parameter is a copy of the reference to the string. Changing the copy inside the function by assigning a new reference to it won't change the original.

If you pass in an object or array, you can change the items in them without the need to change the reference to the object or array:

```
function changeSomethingsValue(thingToChange) {
  thingToChange[0] = "something else";
}

var something = [ "something" ];

changeSomethingsValue(something);

console.log(something[0]); // prints out "something else"
```

A common pattern when a function should have one value as input and a changed value as output is to return the value:

```
function changeSomethingsValue(thingToChange) {
  return thingToChange + " else";
}

var something = "something";

something = changeSomethingsValue(something);

console.log(something); // prints out "something else"
```